# Filter user post data in sails.js

Tags: node.js, post, model, sails.js

I would like to create/update a model in controller as:

```
User.create(postData)
```

and postData is supposed to be something like:

```
{name:'Walter Jr', password: '123', gender: 1}
```

But what if a malicious user post something like:

```
{name:'Walter Jr', password: '123', gender: 1, anExtraAttribute: 'HAHA'}
```

I tested and anExtraAttribute was saved to the database.

So is there a way to filter the postData and leave only the attributes defined in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to set `schema : true` under config/models.js

File models.js can be like :

```
module.exports.models = {

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Your app's default connection. i.e. the name of one of your app's        *
  * connections (see `config/connections.js`)                                *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  connection : 'localDiskDb',

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * How and whether Sails will attempt to automatically rebuild the          *
  * tables/collections/etc. in your schema.                                  *
  *                                                                          *
  * See http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html  *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  migrate : 'alter',

  schema : true

};
```

Comment: Thanks! For others, refer to the [official doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=schema).

Comment: An extra question: What if I don't want the user to add an associated record by calling create()? For example: **Student.create({name:'John', department:{name: 'YouCanNotCreateANewDepartment'});**. Should I manually delete **department** attribute from postData?

Comment: Yes but you can implement beforeValidate under your model file to do this properly